# how to set $_POST as public property or variable in classes in php

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to set `$url = $_POST['url'];` as public property in a class, but the editor won't let me. Why is that? Here is my code below:

```
class insertAd {
  public $uploadOk = 0;
  public $newVar1 = 0;
```

Here I want: `$url = $_POST['url'];`

```
  function chkEmptyBoxes() {

    $url = $_POST['url'];

    $start_time = (int) $_POST['start_time'];
    $end_time = (int) $_POST['end_time'];
    $arr = array("Url" => "$url", "Start Time" => "$start_time", "End Time" => "$end_time");

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
      if (empty($val)) {
        echo "<b>" . $key . "</b>" . " " . "require: ";
        $this->uploadOk = 0;
      } else {
        $this->uploadOk = 1;
        $this->newVar1 = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot assign to the variable inside the class, you need to make a function that sets the value of the variable to `$_POST['url']`

Comment: how ? can you show little example pls

Comment: add `public $url = "" `

Comment: adding public before $url = $_POST['']; not working i have tried already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phplover already stated, you need to set the variable.

In your example:

```
class insertAd {
    public $uploadOk = 0;
    public $newVar1 = 0;
    public $url;

    // When you instantiate the class, set the $url to the specific value.
    public function __construct() {

        /* check, if the url's matches a specific pattern and it is a valid url
         * Better safe than sorry.
         */
        if(filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        {
            {
                $this->url = $_POST['url'];
            }
        }
    }

    function chkEmptyBoxes() {

        $start_time = (int) $_POST['start_time'];
        $end_time = (int) $_POST['end_time'];

        $arr = array("Url" => $this->url, "Start Time" => "$start_time", "EndTime" => "$end_time");

        foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            if (empty($val)) {
                echo "<b>" . $key . "</b>" . " " . "require: ";
                $this->uploadOk = 0;
            } 
            else {
                $this->uploadOk = 1;
                $this->newVar1 = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that you want to sanitize the user_input! This is a pretty important thing. Don't rely on the sanity of users.

Comment: Another method is to set the variable through __construct. When setting up the class you pass the POST data.

Comment: good idea, i'll add that to the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to assign a value to a global variable `$url` from inside a class function. Try this:

```
...
function chkEmptyBoxes() {

    $GLOBALS['url'] = $_POST['url'];

    $start_time = (int) $_POST['start_time'];
...
```

If it doesn't work, set $url to an initial value on a global scope, before calling this class function.